# How to simulate a buffet with threads and locks

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, locks

Hello I am working on a simulation of a buffer where I need to use threads and locks. So I created two function one so the consumer gets his trail and the second one is once he gets his trail he can go to the next line to get his meal.
However my code never stops running and never goes to the second function were he could get his meal.

```
from concurrent.futures import thread
import random
import threading
import time
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import traceback
from numpy import number



#Creating the two queues with 50 students
consumers = [x+1 for x in range(50)]
trail = []
meal = []

#putting the locks for both queues
meal_lock = threading.Lock()
trail_lock = threading.Lock()

def trail(x):
    global trail_lock
    while True:
        trail_lock.acquire()
        trail.append(x)
        if x in trail:
            print(f"Consumer {x} Got his trail")
        trail_lock.release()

def meal(x):
    global meal_lock
    while True:
        meal_lock.acquire()
        if x in trail:
            trail.remove(x)
            print("Got his meal")
            meal.append(x)
        meal_lock.release()
        break

number_of_meals = 5
number_of_trails = 5
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_trails) as executor:
    executor.map(trail, range(number_of_trails))
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_meals) as executor:
        executor.map(meal, range(1+y,number_of_meals))
```

Comment: Did you maybe mean to say "tray" instead of "trail?" https://www.webstaurantstore.com/cambro-1826cl163-camlite-18-x-26-red-tray-case/2141826CLRRD.html

Comment: Your `trail(x)` function never returns. There is no `break` or `return` out of the `while True:` loop. Also, it continually calls `trail.append(x)`, again and again, every time around the loop. Assuming you meant to say "tray" instead of "trail," _surely_ the consumer only needs one tray! It looks as if you have not thought deeply about how to solve this problem. I personally would do it in a more object-oriented way: I'd have a `Person` class, a `Tray` class, and classes to represent the supply of trays and the supply of meals... Trying to more closely model real people at a real buffet.